# Place an image with plotly.js

Tags: javascript, json, image, plotly, background-image

I want to color an image in ZAXIS instead of the brown color, but I have only been able to color the background with colors

My code in javascript

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import axios from 'axios';

const TimeSpaceCubePlot = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const fileContent = e.target.result;
      setData(JSON.parse(fileContent));
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
  };

  //probando los layout
  const customLayout = {
    scene: {
      xaxis: {
        backgroundcolor: "rgb(200, 200, 230)",
        gridcolor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        showbackground: true,
        zerolinecolor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      },
      yaxis: {
        backgroundcolor: "rgb(230, 200, 230)",
        gridcolor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        showbackground: true,
        zerolinecolor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      },
      zaxis: {
        backgroundcolor: "rgb(230, 230, 200)",
        gridcolor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        showbackground: true,
        zerolinecolor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        background: {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', // Fondo transparente
          source: 'https://ec.viajandox.com/uploads/diverse_country_publication_85.jpg', // here I want an image
        },
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      {data && (
        <Plot
          data={data}  // Coloca aquí tus datos en el formato adecuado para Plotly.js
          layout={{
            title: 'Time-Space Cube PRO',
            scene: {
              // xaxis: { title: 'X-axis' },
              // yaxis: { title: 'Y-axis' },
              // zaxis: { title: 'Z-axis' },
              ...customLayout.scene // Agregar el diseño personalizado
            }
          }}
          config={{ responsive: true }}
          useResizeHandler={true}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimeSpaceCubePlot;
```

The JSON file that I use to enter the code DATA:

```
[
  {
    "type": "scatter3d",
    "mode": "lines+markers",
    "x": [
      -8.090169943749475,
      -7.878679656440357,
      -7.454974257149478
    ],
    "y": [
      -4.44089209850063e-15,
      -0.9863613034027223,
      -1.9733618518006746
    ],
    "z": [
      0,
      1,
      2
    ],
    "line": {
      "width": 6,
      "color": [
        0,
        1,
        2
      ],
      "colorscale": "Viridis"
    },
    "marker": {
      "size": 3.5,
      "color": [
        0,
        1,
        2
      ],
      "colorscale": "Greens",
      "cmin": -20,
      "cmax": 50
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Just a tip: `new Response(file).json().then(setData)`